# Emit and Broadcast functon exchanging the input value not working

Tags: angularjs, emit

I am trying to update the parent controller `$scope` value into child controller `$scope` value using broadcasting as expected working, but not updating while trying to update the child `$scop`e value to parent `$scope` value by emit function. This is my code:

```js
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.firstRegister = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('broadcast', $scope.name)
  };


  $scope.$on('emit', function(events, args) {
    $scope.name = args;

  });

});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.$on('broadcast', function(events, args) {
    $scope.name = args;
  });

  $scope.secondRegister = function() {
    $rootScope.$emit('emit', $scope.name)
  };
```

```html
  
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl" class="ng-scope">
<input ng-model="name" />
<button ng-click="firstRegister()">Parent</button>

<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl" class="ng-scope">
  <input ng-model="name" />
  <button ng-click="secondRegister()">Child</button>
</div>

</div>
```

plnkr link : http://plnkr.co/edit/l9qD0ZO4MptnWx6u3U9c?p=preview

Comment: why don't you use `service/factory` instead of this event driven approach..?

Comment: This seems like a convoluted approach. Use services to communicate between controllers. You could also (although not recommended) just set values on the rootscope from controllers - so why use a broadcast pattern?

Comment: Only the $scope value has to be exchanged between the parent and child controllers as per my requirement so that i tried using the event approach(broadcast and emit).  May I know the issue from my code.

Comment: You shouldn't use $rootscope in this way - generally 99% of cases is wrong to use $rootscope as a storage / sharing mechanism . It's lazy. Services/Factories are there for that purpose and can be injected into others that require that dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm broadcasting/emitting event in `rootscope` then catch the same event in `rootscope`.Here is the working plunkr can see the [click on this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/HaOdxX5DmARMRQamSXld?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);


app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.firstRegister = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('broadcast', $scope.name)
  };


  $rootScope.$on('emit', function(events, args) {
    $scope.name = args;
  });

});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  $rootScope.$on('broadcast', function(events, args) {
    $scope.name = args;
  });

  $scope.secondRegister = function($event) {
    $rootScope.$emit('emit', $scope.name)
  } ;
});
```